# Python PY files do not reflect changes

Tags: python, django, apache

I have experience with PHP but now have to manage a python application. It is already developed and running on live server. On live server we have beta.domain.com as well. which has its own copy of same source, other than the main domain application.

Now, when we print something within template it effects but before that, following MVC, if we try to print or use `sys.exit()` in `manage.py` or later imported "settings.py" or then `views.py`, nothing effects these files at all. After any change in just mentioned files, Website still renders everything and display related template.

Another thing that if even we remove

```
return render_to_response('home.html', RequestContext(request, context))
```

inside the `views.py` for testing, nothing effects and website still gets rendered with template.

Do I need to think that if website code is already hosted then in order to have changes to reflect new one in the code in any file (.py), needs to be reinitialized by executing any project related file?

I am not sure how python code needs to be updated at all, any quick help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using mod_wsgi?

Comment: That's what I am not familiar about

Comment: Though I have SSH access of server for everything, but not sure how can I figure out, what is there

Comment: Edit your post with you apache configuration, that's a start. (The VirtualHost for your website should be enough)

Comment: Just checked HTTPD.conf file where "LoadModule wsgi_module        libexec/apache22/mod_wsgi.so" can be seen active.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anytime you change your code, you need to restart Apache server.

```
<path to apache>/bin/apachectl restart
```

The python interpreter of the process has already loaded your python modules in previous web requests. And once the module is loaded, it is stored in memory. Next time when a request comes, the Python interpreter will simply use the version of the module that is already loaded in memory. So your changed code will not be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

Please, please, please don't try and edit files on your live server. You're only going to get yourself into terrible difficulties. Use a local copy for development, preferably cloned via a version control system, and deploy at regular intervals rather than on every change.

To answer your question, you usually need to restart the WSGI process in order to see Python code changes. An easy way to do this is to `touch` the .wsgi file, at which point mod_wsgi will detect that it has changed, and reload everything. Otherwise you can simply reload Apache.

Unfortunately I don't understand your references to manage.py or sys.exit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and live server means, we are working on sub domain which is not for users as mentioned BETA.XXX.COM

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "appstore.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

Comment: Is there anyway that I can find .wsgi file using SSH as I have root access of server?

Comment: That random code you have posted in the comment does not help. What is it for? What does it have to do with your problem? And if you don't know how your code is being hosted or run, you should find out before asking random people on the internet.

Comment: It was not a random request Daniel, you asked about the manage.py and that is the code from that file. I hope you understand that

Comment: I know what manage.py is. I just don't understand what relevance it has or why you brought it up in the question.

Comment: You asked about that's why brought up other wise Daniel my question was simple that why changes are not reflecting from py files?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is excatly restarting the apache server as answered by Sudipta .Each time the py files are interpretted .pvc files are created for each corresponding .py files.When the Apache server is restarted all the python source files are interprretted again and new .pvc files are  generated and only these files will run till the apache restarts again.